# find closest parent .classOne or .classTwo jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two different lists of comments in the same page, the first one uses `ul` and the second one `dl`.

**PROBLEM**

I want to color both elements when clicking `button`

I don't want to create a new variable. I want to know if possible something like:

```
  var Comment = $(document).find("[data-href='post?s=" + id_comment + "']").closest("li.comment || dd.listed_comment");
```

Using `OR` or so

```js
$(document).on("click", 'button', function(){
var id_comment =$(this).data("id_comment");
var Comment = $(document).find("[data-href='post?s=" + id_comment + "']").closest("li.comment"); 

Comment.css("background","red");
});
```

```css
li,dd{border:1px solid blue;margin:5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="comments">
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=16'>Comment</div></li>
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=25'>Comment</div></li>
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=26'>Comment</div></li>
</ul>

<dl class="listed_comments">
<dd class="listed_comment"><div data-href='post?s=25'>Comment</div></dd>
 <dd class="listed_comment"><div data-href='post?s=24'>Comment</div></dd>
</dl>

<button data-id_comment="25">Color red</button>
```

Comment: var Comment = $(document).find("[data-href='post?s=" + id_comment + "']").closest("li.comment, dd.listed_comment");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery allows the use of CSS selectors. Part of CSS is the use of multiple selectors, separated by commas. That allows you to select one or the other easily.

```js
$(document).on("click", 'button', function(){
var id_comment =$(this).data("id_comment");
var Comment = $(document).find("[data-href='post?s=" + id_comment + "']").closest("li.comment, dd.listed_comment"); 

Comment.css("background","red");
});
```

```css
li,dd{border:1px solid blue;margin:5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="comments">
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=16'>Comment</div></li>
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=25'>Comment</div></li>
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=26'>Comment</div></li>
</ul>

<dl class="listed_comments">
<dd class="listed_comment"><div data-href='post?s=25'>Comment</div></dd>
 <dd class="listed_comment"><div data-href='post?s=24'>Comment</div></dd>
</dl>

<button data-id_comment="25">Color red</button>
```

Of course, the easiest way of doing this would be to use a common class across both elements (e.g., "comment-container").

Comment: Don't know why this got down-voted. OP specifically asked if there was a way to do something like an `OR` (`||`) operator. In CSS that's a `,` comma operator.

Comment: @David784 Thanks. I've got "fans" that like to downvote everything I post.

Comment: `li.comment, dd.listed_comment` this is awesome. I'll try this out. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses CSS style selectors. See the code below, where I've simply searched for any matching element, then selected - and applied CSS - to its parent.

```js
$(document).on("click", 'button', function(){
 var id_comment =$(this).data("id_comment");
 $('div[data-href="post?s=' + id_comment + '"]').parent().css("background","red");
});
```

```css
li,dd{border:1px solid blue;margin:5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="comments">
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=16'>Comment</div></li>
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=25'>Comment</div></li>
 <li class="comment"><div data-href='post?s=26'>Comment</div></li>
</ul>

<dl class="listed_comments">
<dd class="listed_comment"><div data-href='post?s=25'>Comment</div></dd>
 <dd class="listed_comment"><div data-href='post?s=24'>Comment</div></dd>
</dl>

<button data-id_comment="25">Color red</button>
```